# ionic cordova build android --prod --release

Tags: cordova, ionic3

Tengo un proyecto realizado en ionic3, el cuál tengo problemas al momento de generar el `--release` del proyecto para la plataforma de `android`. El modo debug de android y el release de IOS funciona perfectamente, pero al momento de generar el APK para subir a Play Store me genera el siguiente error:

```
λ ionic cordova build android --prod --release
Running app-scripts build: --prod --platform android --target cordova
[17:41:16]  build prod started ...
[17:41:16]  clean started ...
[17:41:16]  clean finished in 51 ms
[17:41:16]  copy started ...
[17:41:16]  deeplinks started ...
[17:41:17]  deeplinks finished in 869 ms
[17:41:17]  ngc started ...
[17:41:36]  ngc finished in 18.93 s
[17:41:36]  preprocess started ...
[17:41:36]  copy finished in 20.13 s
[17:41:36]  preprocess finished in 121 ms
[17:41:36]  webpack started ...
[17:43:00]  webpack finished in 83.38 s
[17:43:00]  uglifyjs started ...
[17:43:00]  sass started ...
[17:43:05]  sass finished in 5.26 s
[17:43:05]  cleancss started ...
[17:43:29]  cleancss finished in 24.27 s
[17:43:39]  uglifyjs finished in 39.38 s
[17:43:39]  postprocess started ...
[17:43:39]  postprocess finished in 81 ms
[17:43:39]  lint started ...
[17:43:39]  build prod finished in 143.21 s
> cordova build android --release
Android Studio project detected

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
[17:43:48]  tslint: c:/MyApp/src/providers/mfp-serviceinvoker.ts, line: 161
            Duplicate variable: 'resourceRequest'

     L161:  publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
                    var Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools_old' (Expected 'C:\Users\users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools')
Already observed package id 'tools' in 'C:\Users\users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools_old'
Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools_old_new' (Expected 'C:\Users\users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools')
rAlready observed package id 'tools' in 'C:\Users\users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools_old_new'
Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools_otro_new' (Expected 'C:\Users\users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools')
eAlready observed package id 'tools' in 'C:\Users\users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools_otro_new'
sourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest( url, metodo, timeout);
     L162:                      resourceRequest.setQueryParameters(parametros);

[17:43:48]  tslint: c:/MyApp/src/providers/mfp-serviceinvoker.ts, line: 233
            Duplicate variable: 'headers'

     L233:                       var headers = new Headers();
     L234:                       params = this.appendParams( params, parametros );

[17:43:48]  tslint: c:/MyApp/src/providers/mfp-serviceinvoker.ts, line: 199
            'metodo' is declared but never used.

     L199:                  var metodo;
     L200:                  //Invoke using POST Method

[17:43:48]  tslint: c:/MyApp/src/providers/mfp-serviceinvoker.ts, line: 3
            'Http' is declared but never used.

       L2:  import { Constantes } from "../utils/constantes";
       L3:  import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

[17:43:48]  tslint: c:/MyApp/src/providers/mfp-serviceinvoker.ts, line: 3
            'RequestOptions' is declared but never used.

       L2:  import { Constantes } from "../utils/constantes";
       L3:  import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

[17:43:48]  tslint: c:/MyApp/src/pages/login/login.ts, line: 11
            'FormBuilder' is declared but never used.

      L10:           Events } from 'ionic-angular';
      L11:  import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
      L12:  import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

[17:43:48]  tslint: c:/MyApp/src/pages/registration/registration.ts, line: 9
            'FormBuilder' is declared but never used.

       L8:           NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
       L9:  import { FormBuilder,
      L10:           Validators } from '@angular/forms';

[17:43:48]  tslint: c:/MyApp/src/pages/passwordRecovery/password-recovery.ts, line: 2
            'FormBuilder' is declared but never used.

       L1:  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
       L2:  import { FormBuilder,
       L3:           Validators } from '@angular/forms';

[17:43:48]  tslint: c:/MyApp/src/pages/settings/edit-user.ts, line: 9
            All imports on this line are unused.

       L8:           Events } from 'ionic-angular';
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_ag6mru1kfg4vo07ecetmn2ljx.run(C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build.gradle:145)
mport { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
      L10:  // Pages

[17:43:48]  tslint: c:/MyApp/src/providers/get-token.ts, line: 2
            'Http' is declared but never used.

       L1:  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
       L2:  import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
       L3:  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

[17:43:48]  tslint: c:/MyApp/src/pipes/highlight-match.pipe.ts, line: 2
            'PipeTransform' is declared but never used.

       L1:  import { Pipe,
       L2:           PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

[17:43:48]  tslint: c:/MyApp/src/pages/settings/settings.ts, line: 15
            'FormBuilder' is declared but never used.

      L14:  import { EditUser } from './edit-user';
      L15:  import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
      L16:  import { Registration } from '../registration/registration';

[17:43:48]  tslint: c:/MyApp/src/providers/push-functions.ts, line: 75
            'extractDeviceId' is declared but never used.

      L75:  function extractDeviceId(message : String){
      L76:      var deviceId = "";

[17:43:48]  lint finished in 9.09 s
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:platformAttrExtractor
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:javaPreCompileRelease
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes

NO-SOURCE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease
 UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:extractProguardFiles
 UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild
 UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseResources
 UP-TO-DATE
:app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseManifest
 UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseResources
 UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileRelease
 UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
 UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE

:app:lintVitalRelease

:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseShaders
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets
UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseShaders
 UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets

:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithStackFramesFixerForRelease
 UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDesugarForRelease
 UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseJavaRes
 NO-SOURCE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
 UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease

ProGuard, version 5.3.3
Reading input...

Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\0.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\2.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\3.jar] (filtered)

Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\4.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\5.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\6.jar] (filtered)

Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\7.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\8.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\9.jar] (filtered)

Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\10.jar] (filtered)

Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\11.jar] (filtered)

Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\12.jar] (filtered)

Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\13.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\14.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\15.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\16.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\17.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\18.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\19.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\20.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\21.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\22.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\23.jar] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\24.jar] (filtered)
Reading program directory [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\release\1] (filtered)
Reading program jar [C:\MyApp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJavaRes\release\0.jar] (filtered)
Reading library jar [C:\Users\users\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Users\users\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-23\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar]

Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslError]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate$DName]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.HostNameResolver]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpParams]
Note: there were 7 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)

Initializing...
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult$ReleasableResultGuardian'
Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability: can't find referenced method 'android.app.NotificationChannel getNotificationChannel(java.lang.String)' in library class android.app.NotificationManager
Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setChannelId(java.lang.String)' in library class android.app.Notification$Builder
Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability: can't find referenced class android.app.NotificationChannel
Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability: can't find referenced class android.app.NotificationChannel
Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability: can't find referenced method 'void createNotificationChannel(android.app.NotificationChannel)' in library class android.app.NotificationManager
Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability: can't find referenced class android.app.NotificationChannel
Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability: can't find referenced class android.app.NotificationChannel
Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.config.GservicesValue: can't find referenced method 'android.content.Context createDeviceProtectedStorageContext()' in library class android.content.Context
Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.config.GservicesValue: can't find referenced method 'boolean isUserUnlocked()' in library class android.os.UserManager
Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.wrappers.InstantApps: can't find referenced method 'boolean isInstantApp()' in library class android.content.pm.PackageManager
Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.wrappers.PackageManagerWrapper: can't find referenced method 'boolean isInstantApp(java.lang.String)' in library class android.content.pm.PackageManager
Warning: com.google.android.gms.gcm.zzd: can't find referenced method 'android.app.NotificationChannel getNotificationChannel(java.lang.String)' in library class android.app.NotificationManager
Warning: com.google.android.gms.gcm.zzd: can't find referenced class android.app.NotificationChannel
Warning: com.google.android.gms.gcm.zzd: can't find referenced class android.app.NotificationChannel
Warning: com.google.android.gms.gcm.zzd: can't find referenced method 'void createNotificationChannel(android.app.NotificationChannel)' in library class android.app.NotificationManager
Warning: com.google.android.gms.gcm.zzd: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setChannelId(java.lang.String)' in library class android.app.Notification$Builder
Warning: com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushIntentService: can't find referenced class android.app.NotificationChannel
Warning: com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushIntentService: can't find referenced class android.app.NotificationChannel
Warning: com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushIntentService: can't find referenced class android.app.NotificationChannel
Warning: com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushIntentService: can't find referenced method 'void createNotificationChannel(android.app.NotificationChannel)' in library class android.app.NotificationManager
Warning: com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushIntentService: can't find referenced method 'Notification$Builder(android.content.Context,java.lang.String)' in library class android.app.Notification$Builder
Warning: com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushIntentService: can't find referenced class android.app.NotificationChannel
Warning: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl: can't find referenced method 'long getContentLengthLong()' in program class com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl
Warning: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl: can't find referenced method 'long getHeaderFieldLong(java.lang.String,long)' in program class com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced method 'long getContentLengthLong()' in library class java.net.HttpURLConnection
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced method 'long getHeaderFieldLong(java.lang.String,long)' in library class java.net.HttpURLConnection
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Note: com.google.android.gms.common.util.WorkSourceUtil: can't find dynamically referenced class android.os.WorkSource$WorkChain

Note: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform: can't find dynamically referenced class com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLParametersImpl
Note: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform: can't find dynamically referenced class org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLParametersImpl
Note: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform: can't find dynamically referenced class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl
Note: com.worklight.common.security.PRNGFixes: can't find dynamically referenced class org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto
Note: com.worklight.common.security.PRNGFixes: can't find dynamically referenced class org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto
Note: okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform: can't find dynamically referenced class com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLParametersImpl
Note: okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform: can't find dynamically referenced class org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLParametersImpl
Note: okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform: can't find dynamically referenced class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown field 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult$ReleasableResultGuardian mResultGuardian' in class 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.LifecycleCallback { com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.LifecycleFragment getChimeraLifecycleFragmentImpl(com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.LifecycleActivity); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.LifecycleActivity'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.common.images.internal.LoadingImageView { void setOnImageLoadedListener(com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager$OnImageLoadedListener); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager$OnImageLoadedListener'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.google.android.gms.common.images.internal.LoadingImageView { void setClipPathProvider(com.google.android.gms.common.images.internal.LoadingImageView$ClipPathProvider); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.google.android.gms.common.images.internal.LoadingImageView$ClipPathProvider'
Note: there were 1 references to unknown classes.
Warning: there were 30 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Warning: there were 14 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
      You should check your configuration for typos.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
Note: there were 1 references to unknown class members.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
Note: there were 3 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
      (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
Note: there were 9 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (c:\MyApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:9828) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9828) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Ionic info

```
λ ionic info
cli packages: (C:\Users\users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

System:

    Node : v8.11.1
    npm  : 6.1.0
    OS   : Windows 7

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set
Misc:
    backend : pro
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo logré solucionar. Abrí la plataforma de android como aplicación en Android Studio y me pidió actualizar incompatibilidad de dependencias. Luego de eso, generé la APK firmada sin ningún problema.

La plataforma de android era la que se genera en platform/android